# Render result different from material view

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, world

I am designing a shield, the problem is, on the material view all looks wonderful, but once I change it to world or render the image it looks awful.

[image: Material Preview]

You can see it above how it looks, now if I change the view to the "Display Render Preview" it will look like this:

[image: Render Preview]

You guys can see that it is a new project, the only thing I did was set the texture to the cube, the plane and set the world
What an I missing?

Comment: Classic misconception: Material view uses a quick-and-dirty, built-in lighting and hdr solution to make the scene look nice. Your scene doesn't look as nice in render mode because you are using a single, default light, have not set up an hdr environment texture, and have not turned on any sexy processing effects in the Render tab.

Comment: Oh, I see, I will set a enviroment texture.

Answer (score 1):

As hatinacat2000 mentioned in the comments, reflective scenes look terrible untill you give them some complex lighting information. The best way to do this is by adding an HDRI environment to your scene.

HDRI's not only provide a picture background, they also give lighting and color information that is used in reflections.

To add an HDRI, go to the SHADING tab, change the selection from OBJECT to WORLD, add an ENVIRONMENT TEXTURE, and give it an image (equi-rectangular are preferred).

The HDRI's that come built in with blender are in the blender folder at `../2.83/datafiles/studiolights/world` - (.exr files). However, other image formats such as .jpeg, and .png work as well. If you want a bigger selection, there are plenty of places on line to get them for free - one of the most popular is HDRI-Haven (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/).

[image: HDRIHookup]

Comment: I have set a texture now, it looks nice, thanks Cristopher.